# How can I find all the classes which used a known class as its property in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm working on investigation for the code of a Java project. I'm wondering in eclipse if there's any way/shortcut key to find out all classes which used a known class as its property or imported the known class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set the cursor on the class definition of your known class (like `public class SomeClass`, then position the cursor on `SomeClass`)
- Open context menu (right mouse button)
- Select `References/Project` (or `References/Workspace` if you want to search all projects in your workspace)

This will give you a list of all occurrences of your known class in the `Search` panel.